# How can I access the content of a widget outside the constructor?

Tags: qt, widget

I want to display the content I wrote in the QLineEdit widget after clicking on the QPushButton with the function ShowMessage(). How can I access that content outside of the constructor?

Tried putting the QLineEdit object I created in to a private variable.

My CPP file

```
#include "manualwidget.h"
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QMessageBox>

ManualWidget::ManualWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);
    QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
    QPushButton *pushButton = new QPushButton(this);
    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout();

    label->setText("Enter text:");
    pushButton->setText("Ok");
    layout->addWidget(label);
    layout->addWidget(lineEdit);
    layout->addWidget(pushButton);

    setLayout(layout);

    connect(pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this ,SLOT(showMessage()));
    connect(lineEdit, SIGNAL(returnPressed()),this, SLOT(showMessage()));


}

void ManualWidget::showMessage(){

    QMessageBox::information(this, "Message", "The text entered in the "
     "manual widget window is:\n" + m_lineEdit->text());

}
```

My header file

```
#ifndef MANUALWIDGET_H
#define MANUALWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QLineEdit>

class ManualWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ManualWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

signals:


public slots:

private slots:
    void showMessage();
private:
    QLineEdit m_lineEdit;
};

#endif // MANUALWIDGET_H
```

Comment: remove `QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);` and change `layout->addWidget(lineEdit);` to `layout->addWidget(&m_lineEdit);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@eyllanesc suggestion might work, but it should not be a prefered approach. Qt has its' own memory model, and usage of it should be prefered. Thus, "QLineEdit m_lineEdit" should be changed to e.g. "QLineEdit* m_lineEdit", and in constructor you should initialize it in the following way:

```
// Instance of the QLineEdit will be owned by the ManualWidget which is part of Qt memory management now.
m_lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
```

Then, the following line:

```
layout->addWidget(lineEdit);
```

Can be changed to:

```
layout->addWidget(m_lineEdit);
```

Why is it bad to use "QLineEdit m_lineEdit"? Because Qt might want to destroy this object for some reason (you still can call m_lineEdit.deleteLater()) and you might end up in the "double destruction" situation which would result in app being crashed. You can say that in this way conflicting memory models would interact.

Comment: thanks a lot! It works now, it was actually such an obvious answer. Oh well I'm still learning.